# How to create a page without any theme via custom module?

Tags: 7, theming

I created a page using a custom module, it has a template file too and it works well. But when i visit my page it shows wrapped by my default theme, it's obvious. The thing is that i would like to show that content in a clean page.

Is there a function or something that lets me do it? without modules like ThemeKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show content in clean page you can use theme_hook_suggestions in `THEME_preprocess_html` and `THEME_preprocess_page` with passing some GET variable.
For example for clean pages you can add `$_GET['embed'] = 1` and in `preprocess functions` write the following code:

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (isset($_GET['embed'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__embed';
  }
}

function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($_GET['embed'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__embed';
  }
}
```

Then copy paste `html.tpl.php` and `page.tpl.php` and rename to `html--embed.tpl.php` and `page--embed.tpl.php`. Ultimately remove unnecessary code from template files.